# Style a QFrame with CSS depending on the frameShape in Qt 6

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qt6, qframe

Using the Fusion style, both a `QFrame` with a `HLine` and `VLine` `frameShape` set are displayed as a 1px black line. Up to Qt 5.15, the appearance could be changed with style sheets. E.g. this made such a `QFrame` a gray line:

```
QApplication application(argc, argv);
application.setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral(
    // This prevents HLine and VLine QFrames to be a black line
    "QFrame[frameShape=\"4\"],"
    "QFrame[frameShape=\"5\"] { "
        "color: palette(Mid); "
    "}"));
```

Using Qt 6, this setting seems to be ignored. I also tried to use some literal color like `color: red` or `border: 1px solid red` to see it's about the `palette` value, but the setting is still not applied. Leaving out the `[frameShape=...]` selector makes all `QFrame`s being styled like the respective setting, so apparently, this is about the `[frameShape=...]` selector.

I tried to use e.g. `frameShape=\"0x0004\"` and also e.g. `frameShape=\"QFrame::HLine\"`. This also didn't work.

According to the docs, the `QFrame::Shape` enum remains unchanged. Is this not implemented yet (I tried it with Qt 6.2.3), or does one have to access this in another way in Qt 6?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a regression in Qt. I filed a bug report about this: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-101877